# Secondary horizontal axis: Wavelength (nm) and Energy(eV) on the same plot in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Is it possible to create in Excel a dual-horizontal axis plot, showing on the top horizontal axis the Energy and on the bottom the Wavelength (both on x-axis)?
The energy is related to wavelength using this equation: Energy (eV)= 1240/Wavelength (nm).
Simply creating "secondary axis" does not work. 
Below are some examples that were created using different software.
Many thanks in advance!

[The required Energy/Wavelength dual axis plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnjzK.jpg)
[Here is another view of the dual x-axis plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIU4r.jpg)